# How do I remove a custom item name from an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The other day, I renamed a sword to `My Awesome Sword` in an anvil. I've decided that I don't like the custom name anymore and want to remove it.

The problem is, the anvil doesn't seem to be able to remove a custom name applied earlier. When I clear the text field, this is what I see:

[image: Anvil]

Notice how I cleared the text box for custom name, but the sword still has the first letter? When I take it out, now I have a sword named `M`.

Can I remove a previously applied custom name from an anvil? I would prefer not to enable cheats on my world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like 1.13 changed the anvil's workings a little. In 1.12, clearing the text field would have worked, but in 1.13, it keeps the first letter instead of clearing the custom name.

But, there is still a way to use the anvil to clear a previously applied custom name. You just need to enter one or more spaces into the text box:

[image: Anvil2]

And voila, the custom name is gone!

[image: Item data after removing parts.]

Comment: Just checked and it still works in 1.18